# Read and download the contents of a multiple gzip files from s3 bucket and convert the format in python

Tags: python

I am trying to read/download the contents from s3 bucket and format them into json. I have connected the s3 bucket and pulled the files. Got the multiple files and i need to iterate through every file and download the data in local path.

```
file1.gz
file2.gz
file3.gz
```

each file has the content in the below format

```
b'{"id": "1", "name": " value1"}\n{"id":"2", name": "value2"}\n{"id":"3", "name": "value3"}\n'
```

What i was trying to do is, iterate through every file and download the contents of all files into one and convert the format from bytes to json.

Comment: first create function to download single file, next create function to uncompress and convert  this single file, convert JSON to dictionary and append to one list, and later run it in `for`-loop with list of files.

Comment: you can split your content in separated rows and use `json.loads(text)` with every row separatelly and you will get it as Python's dictionares which you can later convert to other structure and later convert to JSON